# Error subscript

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I got that error a while ago and I'm not sure, what's wrong. The Post is just normal custom class with two attributes of type String and int.

> web api :http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
>
> PostService :

```
class PostService {
var settings:Settings!
init(){

    self.settings = Settings()
}

func getPosts(callback:(NSArray) ->()){
    request(settings.viewPost, callback: callback)


}
func request(url:String , callback:(NSArray) ->() ){


    let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){(data , repsonse , error) in
        //var error:NSError?
        do {
            let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            callback(response)


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

> settings :

```
import Foundation
class Settings {

  var viewPost = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

}
```

> post:

```
class Post {
   var _userId:Int
   var _title: String

   init(userid:Int , title:String){
     self._userId = userid
     self._title = title

   }

   func toJSON() ->String{

    return ""
   }
}
```

> and tableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var postsCollection = [Post]()
var service:PostService!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    service = PostService()
    service.getPosts{
        (response) in
        self.loadPosts(response[" "] as! NSArray )
    }
}

func loadPosts(posts:NSArray){
    for post in posts{

        var userId = post["userId"] as! Int
        var title  = post["title"] as! String
        let postObj = Post(userid: userId, title: title)
        postsCollection.append(postObj)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return postsCollection.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let post = postsCollection[indexPath.row] as NSData
    cell.textLabel?.text = post._userId
    cell.detailTextLabel = post._title
    return cell
}
```

why error Cannot subscript a value of type '[Post]' in line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this **is** the issue but it is an issue.

Since `postsCollection` has a distinct type there is no need to cast the type.
`NSData` is the wrong type anyway.

```
let post = postsCollection[indexPath.row] // the compiler infers to Post
```

Side note: Put the `dispatch` block to reload the table view **after** the repeat loop to create the `Post` instances. Reloading the table view in each iteration of the loop is very expensive and not necessary.

```
for post in posts {
        ...
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And (public) properties starting with a underscore are pretty unusual (in Swift).

PS: There are two further issues

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(post._userId)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = post._title
```

---

**Edit:** Simple working solution, there are only two classes

**`class Post`**

```
class Post : CustomStringConvertible {
  var userId:Int
  var title: String

  init(userid:Int , title:String){
    self.userId = userid
    self.title = title
  }

  var description : String { return String(userId) }
}
```

**`class TableViewController`**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var postsCollection = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){ [unowned self] (data , repsonse , error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!)
      } else {
        do {
          let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
          for post in posts {
            let postObj = Post(userid: post["userId"] as! Int, title: post["title"] as! String)
            self.postsCollection.append(postObj)
          }
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        } catch let error as NSError {
          print(error)
        }
      }
      }.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return postsCollection.count }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let post = postsCollection[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = String(post.userId)
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = post.title
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: tank you :) 
when running is programing crash an error " Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10f2758d8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10f275d60).
(lldb)  "

Comment: There is no casting to `NSDictionary` in your code. The error message says the compiler expects a dictionary but gets an array. I guess the error occurs in the `PostService` class.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean : Side note: Put the dispatch block to reload the table view after the repeat loop to create the Post instances. Reloading the table view in each iteration of the loop is very expensive and not necessary.

Comment: The dispatch block is **inside** the repeat loop `for post in posts` at the moment. It's called in each iteration of the loop which is very inefficient. Put it **outside** the repeat loop right **after** the closing brace then it's called once which is sufficient. I updated the answer.

Comment: when Put it outside the repeat loop  error :Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int in line              self.loadPosts(response[" "] as! NSArray )

Comment: No key subscripting, no casting: `self.loadPosts(response)` but I recommend to use Swift type  `[[String:AnyObject]]` rather than `NSArray`

Comment: i updated post and one question how can i do this program whit alamofire an swiftyjson ?

Comment: IMHO both libraries are overkill for that job.

Comment: Thank you very much @vadian 
Program was executed without error but return nothing  :D

Comment: when i'm printing [postsCollection]. 
inline `print(postsCollection)`,
return
 `[Blogtaculos.Post]
[Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post]
[Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post]
[Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post, Blogtaculos.Post] ....]  `
' why ?
please help me .

Comment: Make your class `Post` conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and add the `description` property returning something more descriptive than the generic dynamic type.

Comment: thanks ,is code correct ?class Post : CustomStringConvertible {
    var _userId:Int
    var _title: String
    
    init(userid:Int , title:String){
        self._userId = userid
        self._title = title
        
    }
    func toJSON() ->String{
    
        return " "
    }
    var description: String {
        var string = String(_userId)
      
        return string
    }
}

Comment: Too complicated, it's just `var description: String { return String(_userId) }`

Comment: sorry can you help me for this question : [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100484/can-i-use-filter-data-in-api-with-json) :D

Comment: The linked question is on hold because it's too broad (see the comments). Basically the code in **this** question does what you're asking in the other question.

Comment: can I conversion this question to two other questions؟

Comment: I added a complete solution

Comment: error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ` in line `        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = post.title`

Comment: I tested it with a standard table view cell and style `Right Detail` to safely have a `detailTextLabel`. From your code I assumed you have that, too. Goto Interface Builder and change the style of the table view cell or change the code to `cell.detailTextLabel?.text` but using the latter option you will get no error but also you will see no title.

Comment: I hope you are not angry with me for too much for questions @vadian